# mysql query not showing the right submit button?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem in which when i check whether two fields in database are having same values then it should display 'add as fan' button but when it is not having that row then it should display 'remove fan' button.

Here is my code:

```
<?
$selectfan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vitfans");
$fanrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectfan);
$fan_following = $fanrow['fan_following'];
$fan_followed = $fanrow['fan_followed'];
if ($fan_following =='$user' && $fan_followed=='$username') {
 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="removefriend" value="Remove fan">';
}
else
{
 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="addfriend" value="Add Me as Fan">';
}
echo $addasfan;
?>
```

but when i click on 'add me as fan' button it again shows 'add as fan' button rather it should show 'remove fan' button but it is not happening, below is a pic of my database for more info.

So, since fan_followed and fan_followed are matching in database as for rahulk and deeksha why is it not showing remove fan in mysql.

[image: Database]

Comment: What is `'$user'` and `'$username'`???

Comment: I thought we already fixed this using `if($fan_following == $fan_followed)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems
1. the $selectfan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vitfans"); will return 3 rows, but you dont refer them as 3 rows you refer them as 1 row.

Which row do you mean by this?
$fan_following = $fanrow['fan_following']; 
$fan_followed = $fanrow['fan_followed'];

2nd , '$user' the the quote? you should not write the single quote. you can write double quotes but it doesnt matter, anyway you shouldn't do it with single quote

Answer (score 0):

Your query should return single for the type of comparison you are using. You can use your condition with single row only. If you wan t to iterate try using "foreach" but I believe that is not what you are looking for.

Also after you add a fan, does you query run again to check for "$user" & "$username"?